# How to round numbers in c?

Tags: c++, rounding

I wrote all the code. It compiles correctly, but I need to help to fix the output. It's just gas cost for 20 miles, 75 miles, and 500 miles.

```
float twentyMiles = 20 / miles * gas;
float seventyFiveMiles = 75 / miles * gas;
float fiveHundredMiles = 500 / miles * gas;

cout << twentyMiles << fixed << setprecision(2);
cout << " ";


cout << seventyFiveMiles << fixed << setprecision(2);
cout << " ";
cout << fiveHundredMiles << fixed << setprecision(2) << endl;
```

I keep getting the right answer but I don't how to round the decimal point for the twenty mile output.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the result? I assume the problem is you set the precision etc after you output `twentyMiles`

Comment: Are we supposed to *guess* the declaration types and proper initialization of `miles` and `gas`. It matters, and should be presented as part of a properly formed [mcve]. Also, you should set precision *before* the output arguments insertion on the stream; not after.

Comment: C is not the same as C++, and numbers do not have decimal points. Only their *representations* have some. See http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1):

You have to output the formatting operators *before* the number(s) that they affect.

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) 
     << twentyMiles << " " 
     << seventyFiveMiles << " " 
     << fiveHundredMiles << endl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
float miles,gas;
float twentyMiles = 20 / (miles * gas);
float seventyFiveMiles = 75 / (miles * gas);
float fiveHundredMiles = 500 / (miles * gas);

cout << twentyMiles << fixed << setprecision(2);
cout << " ";


cout << seventyFiveMiles << fixed << setprecision(2);
cout << " ";
cout << fiveHundredMiles << fixed << setprecision(2) << endl;
```

> Don't forget to include to the library and one more thing is the value of the identifiers "miles" & "gas" you have to set a value for both or set it as user input then the setprecision() function will work and round the value to have only 2 decimal places